# Private Fields (or member variables) in a Racket Class

Tags: class, object, racket

I have a class `counter%` that stores a counter as a field, and provides the method `get-and-inc`, to get the value of the current counter and increment it.

```
(define counter%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (field [counter 0])
     (define/public (get-and-inc)
      (begin0 counter
              (set! counter (add1 counter))))))
```

While this code does accurately count:

```
> (define x (new counter%))
> (send x get-and-inc)
0
> (send x get-and-inc)
1
```

the problem is that counter is now public:

```
> (set-field! counter x 42)
> (send x get-and-inc)
42
> (send x get-and-inc)
43
```

The problem here is that I would like the `counter` field to be private, so that it cannot be modified by someone who has instantiated the class. Is this possible with Racket's class system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. And all you need to do is define it like you would any other variable in the class:

```
(define counter%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (define counter 0)
    (define/public (get-and-inc)
      (begin0 counter
              (set! counter (add1 counter))))))
```

And now when you use it, each object will have its own counter:

```
> (define x (new counter%))
> (define y (new counter%))

> (send x get-and-inc)
0
> (send y get-and-inc)
0
> (send x get-and-inc)
1
> (send y get-and-inc)
1
```

This is because any variables defined in a class that are not methods are assumed to be fields ([according to the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html?q=field#%28part._clfields%29))

> Each field, init-field, and non-method define-values clause in a class declares one or more new fields for the class. Fields declared with field or init-field are public. Public fields can be accessed and mutated by subclasses using inherit-field. Public fields are also accessible outside the class via class-field-accessor and mutable via class-field-mutator (see Field and Method Access). Fields declared with define-values are accessible only within the class.

This means that if you wanted a static variable that is associated with the class, rather than instantiated objects, you need to define it outside of the class. Possibly using a `let` block:

```
(define static-counter%
  (let ([counter 0])
    (class object%
      (super-new)
      (define/public (get-and-inc)
        (begin0 counter
                (set! counter (add1 counter)))))))
```

And now all `static-counter` objects will share the same counter

```
> (define x (new counter%))
> (define y (new counter%))

> (send x get-and-inc)
0
> (send y get-and-inc)
1
> (send x get-and-inc)
2
> (send y get-and-inc)
3
```